# Remove class attribute from tree structure with python

Tags: python

I define a class for binary tree:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, list, left=None, right=None, value=None):
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.list = list
    self.value = value
```

After I build the tree, I want to delete Tree's list attribute.

```
def cleanTree(Tree):
  if Tree is None:
    return
  if Tree.left:
    cleanTree(Tree.left)
  del Tree.list
  if Tree.right:
    cleanTree(Tree.right)
```

But it return NoneType:

```
>>> Tree = Tree()
>>> build(Tree)
>>> newTree = cleanTree(Tree)
>>> vars(newTree)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Comment: del is used to delete key value from dictionary since its not an dict it will show above error

Comment: @PavanKumarTS When i don't use recursion and manual delete, i't ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cleanTree` function doesn't return anything.
Try to do this :

```
def cleanTree(Tree):
  if Tree is None:
    return
  del Tree.list
  if Tree.left:
    cleanTree(Tree.left)
  if Tree.right:
    cleanTree(Tree.right)
  return Tree
```

Comment: But how to return?

Comment: It's ok. Thanks.